# Multidimensional array in alphabetical order (obj c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have an array which holds multiple other arrays each with two strings in them. I want to sort the items in the parent array in alphabetical order according to the first string inside the child array. How would I do this?

Parent Array---
               childArray1 (bString, string)
               childArray2 (dString, string)
               childArray3 (cString, string)
               childArray4 (aString, string)

Change to -->
               childArray4 (aString, string)
               childArray1 (bString, string)
               childArray3 (cString, string)
               childArray2 (dString, string)

So the first string in each child array determines the child array's index in the parent array

Comment: Example to understand please

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to not have a multidimensional array but using a custom object for the values, with a `compare:` method, e.g.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString* firstString;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString* secondString;

- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(MyObject*)object;

@end
```

```
@implementation MyObject

- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(MyObject*)object {
   return [self.firstString compare:object.firstString];
}

@end
```

and then sort the array using:

```
NSArray* sortedObjects = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

If you want to stick to your implementation, then

```
NSArray* sortedObjects = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
   NSString* string1 = [obj1 objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString* string2 = [obj2 objectAtIndex:0];

   return [string1 compare:string2];
}];
```